# How does (neo)vim set $PATH for system(['command'])

Tags: neovim, external-command

When I want to call an external program, I have the option of spawning a shell or not.

`system('my command')` will spawn a shell (executing your .bashrc/etc and all it seems).

`system(['my command'])` will execute the command without a shell, which seems like it's the faster and probably preferred method since you avoid any start up cost.

Imagine I have `do_it` installed to `~/totally/not/standard/bin/do_it`, and I've added that a dir to my `$PATH` in my shell, so it normally works.

If I run `system(['do_it'])` it executes fine in nvim, where as I'd actually expect it to fail because without the shell, it shouldn't know where to find `do_it`.

*Unless* nvim is injecting/resolving the `$PATH` as it was when nvim loaded up. I can't run `system(['echo $PATH'])` to check because `echo` is a builtin.

- Is this whats happening?
- Is it safe to assume that if it works in `system(string)` it will work with `system(list)`?

  - Should I be doing `exepath('do_it')` first to get the full path without spawning a shell, then passing the full path to `system(list)`?
- Why would I ever really want `system(string)` when it's so potentially magnitudes slower (if you have a heavy rc) and `system(list)` seems to inherit your environment anyway?

Comment: Does your system have `/bin/echo` ? You might still be able to echo path. But, at a guess, yes—neovim is a process like any other, and inherits env vars from its parent. It may choose to ignore them, but it may also quite reasonably use them (e.g. when launching it’s own processes)

Comment: For others who are not familar with this, see https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#jobstart(). I think you can run `:echo $PATH` to see what `$PATH` is used for `system([])`. nvim inherits the environment variables from the shell it is invoked. This is why we use `export` when defining `$PATH` etc. You can list all environment variables marked with export by running `$ export -p`.